# using codeigniter - why do european characters not show properly?

Tags: php, codeigniter, character-encoding

When I pass a string with special characters to my view, The special characters are shown as a question mark, eg:

```
$data['make']  = 'Quels pneus Dunlop avez-vous acheté ?';

$this->load->view("form", $data);
```

---

This looks as follows in my view:

[image]

When I type the characters directly into the HTML page they show fine. how can I fix this issue?
**EDIT: The charset is already set to:**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using codeigniters ascii_to_entities function did the trick.

```
$this->load->helper('text');
ascii_to_entities($string);
```

Comment: nops does not help me, in my csv there is a euro sign, things work on localhost but not on server

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it could be a charset conflict. Make your HTML charset declaration UTF8 and save your data as UTF8 in the database or text file.

In your `<head>` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

If you are using [`htmlentities()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to output the data var then consider specifying the character set there as well.

```
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: I have this charset already set. If I paste 'acheté' directly into the view, it appears correctly. It seems as if codeigniter is manipulating the data before it is sent to the view

Comment: So is it coming from a DB? If so which one? Where is the template code?

Comment: no it is not coming from a DB - it is plain text directly typed into the controller

Comment: when I use htmlentities() it works - however all the tags and other html is converted also which is not good obviously...

Comment: OK so you need to verify that your editor is saving the file as UTF8 then.

Answer (score 0):

Save your view page as utf8 and that will do the job

Comment: This seems to be a briefer version of the answer provided by Treffynnon - what does this answer add that theirs does not?